# Momentum Four-Vectors particle physics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, particle-physics, momentum

I am studying Special Relativity, and am really struggling to get my head around four-vectors.

I am looking at the following question. You have a particle of rest mass M and total energy E, which collides with a particle of rest mass m that is at rest. It then wants you to find an equation for the sum of the total energies of the two particles, in the frame in which their centre of mass is at rest.

It states that this is given by $$E'^2= (M^2+m^2)c^4+2Emc^2$$

I just am not sure how to get here. I can get an equation for the total energy of the moving particle, if it is moving with three-vector v in the coordinate system with the particle of rest mass m is at rest, then: $$E=M^2c^4+p^2c^2$$and you also know that the particle with rest mass m has total energy $$E=mc^2$$
From here however, I am not sure how to get to the original equation we want. I was going to consider $g(P+Q,P+Q)$ where P is the four-momentum of the particle with rest mass M, and Q is the four-momentum of the particle with rest mass m, but I am not sure how to go about manipulating this.

Any help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: That second equation should either be $E^2$ on the left side or a square root on the right hand side, otherwise the dimensions aren't equal.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using four-vectors then the first thing to do is to recognize the relationship between any four-momentum, $\mathbf P$, and the mass: $m^2 = \mathbf P^2 = E^2 - \vec p^2$ where $E$ is the energy and $\vec p$ is the three-vector momentum (in units where c=1).

Now, we need to recognize that "the sum of the total energies of the two particles, in the frame in which their centre of mass is at rest" is just a very cumbersome way of saying the mass of the system. So $m^2_{P+Q}=(\mathbf P + \mathbf Q)^2$.

The only tricky part is that you are not given the momentum of the particle with rest mass M, so you will have to solve that from the information given first.